# Pulling from wordpress theme into rails with SimpleRSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, loops, controller, rss

I currently have this code, which pulls the first record from my blog:

```
def blogFeed
  begin
    rss = SimpleRSS.parse(open('http://blog.example.co.uk/feed/').read)
    if rss.items.first.title.length > 80 then
      title = "#{ rss.items.first.title[0..70]} ..."
    else
      title = rss.items.first.title
    end
    date = rss.items.first.pubDate.strftime("%d %B %Y")
    @links = { :title => title, :url => rss.items.first.link, :date => date }

  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
    @links = { :title => "", :url => "#", :date => "" }
  end
  return @links
end
```

This is how I reference it in my view:

```
%span.feed
  %span.bold 
    LATEST BLOG:

  - blog = blogFeed
  - if blog[:title] != ""
    = raw blog[:title]
    %a{ :href => "#{ raw blog[:url] }" } READ MORE
  - else
    %a{ :href => "/blog" } CLICK HERE TO VISIT OUR BLOG
```

This works fine, however I need to use more than just the first blog post, is there a way I can iterate through all of the posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up just putting this in my view:

```
- @rss = SimpleRSS.parse open('http://blog.example.co.uk/feed/')
%p
  Latest blog articles:

  %ul.about
    - @rss.items.first(2).each do |i|
      %li.blog
        %a{:href => "http://blog.example.co.uk/#{i.link}"} #{if i.title.length > 80 then "#{ i.title[0..65]} ..." else "#{i.title}" end}
```